# Can I call another class from the setOnAction parameter in javaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I am a beginner programmer and I learned enough of java, now my goal is to create a calculator using JavaFX for gui and have it as oop as possible so that in practice, it is easy for someone else to modify the program, I have encountered a problem when adding a button and wanting to apply the `setOnAction` method to it, I want to have a separate class for handling the events of buttons but I can't understand how to do that with this particular method

This is the `Gui` class:

```
package calculator;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Gui extends Application {

    InputHandler inputhandler = new InputHandler();

    Button add = new Button();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("HackCalc");


        add.setText("+");
        add.setOnAction(inputhandler);


        StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        layout.getChildren().add(add);

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 330, 500);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have gone as far as creating an instance of the `InputHandler` class which I will show you and passing it in `setOnAction` but it never worked, I had a frustrating `NoSuchMethodException` error.

Now, here's the `InputManager` class:

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;

public  class InputHandler extends Gui implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        if(event.getSource()== add){
            System.out.println("InputHandler works");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(event.getSource()== add)` `add` is not defined here. Also, this check won't work how you currently think.

Comment: @nickb `add` is defined in the parent class (in the same package) so that is not a problem.

Comment: So, what is my problem? This is very brain numbing for me at this point because I have been trying for 3 hours to figure something out, without changing this design, (hopefully) I will easily add features with these 2 classes

Comment: It's not the same `add` button. The one that fires the event is the one that belongs to the `Gui` instance created when you launch the application. The one you refer to in the handle method belongs to the instance created when you do `new InputHandler()`. So the condition in the `if` will not be true.

Comment: @James_D That makes perfect sense, so how do I get around this and get the current instance in the InputManager class instead of making a new instance

Comment: It just doesn't make any sense to make the `InputHandler ` a subclass of `Gui `. An input handler *is not* an application. Why do you need the `if` clause in the handler anyway? Since the handler is only registered with the `add` button (defined in `Gui `), you know that is the source of the event.

Comment: @James_D I'm not very familiar with programming technical terminology but I will try to say this in my own way, I thought it would be more organized and save me time to create the button and organize the layout in the gui class, then add any button functionality in the InputManager.

Comment: Yes, sure, you can do that. But inside that button handler, you already know that the source of the event is the add button (because you called `add.setOnAction(inputHandler)`). So you don't need the`if` statement, or the reference to the add button, in your `InputHandler`.

Comment: @James_D Could you give me some correct code for this, I still don't know how to call another class from setOnAction and when I got rid of the if statement and replaced it with one line of code to print out it works i got this error

Comment: Exception in Application constructor
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: calculator.InputHandler.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:126)

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: I found the problem! I made InputHandler extend Gui then created a new instance of InputHandler in Gui, there was a loop of creating a new InputHandler instance, all credit goes to @James_D I read your explanation in another thread :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all `InputHandler` extending `Gui` does not make sense as design is concerned, since there is not *"is a"* relationship between `InputHandler` and `Gui`/`Application`.

You're better off using a anonymus class/lambda expression as event handler and also get rid of the check for the button, but use different event handlers instead. This way you get rid of all the `if (source == someButton)` checks...

What would make sense is seperating the view from the calculator logic, to make the GUI independent from the calculator logic.

**Example**

```
public class Calculator {

    private final ObservableList<String> formulaParts = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private final ObservableList<String> formulaPartsUnmodifiable = FXCollections.unmodifiableObservableList(formulaParts);
    private final ReadOnlyStringWrapper operandString = new ReadOnlyStringWrapper();
    private Integer operand;
    private Integer previousOperand;
    private IntBinaryOperator operator;
    private boolean operandModifiable = true;

    /** previous input elements as Strings */
    public ObservableList<String> getFormulaParts() {
        return formulaPartsUnmodifiable;
    }

    public final String getOperand() {
        return this.operandString.get();
    }

    /** property contains current input as String */
    public final ReadOnlyStringProperty operandProperty() {
        return this.operandString.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

    public void addDigit(byte digit) {
        if (operandModifiable) {
            operand = operand == null ? digit : operand * 10 + digit;
            operandString.set(Integer.toString(operand));
        }
    }

    public void addBinaryOperator(IntBinaryOperator operator) {
        if (operand != null) {
            if (previousOperand != null) {
                evaluate();
            }

            previousOperand = operand;
            operand = null;
            operandString.set("");
            formulaParts.setAll(Integer.toString(previousOperand), operator.toString());
            this.operator = operator;
            operandModifiable = true;
        }
    }

    public void evaluate() {
        if (operand != null && operator != null) {
            int result = operator.applyAsInt(previousOperand, operand);
            formulaParts.clear();
            operandString.set(Integer.toString(result));
            operandModifiable = false;
            previousOperand = null;

            operand = result;
        }
    }

}
```

```
public class BinaryPlusOperator implements IntBinaryOperator {

    @Override
    public int applyAsInt(int left, int right) {
        return left + right;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "+";
    }

}
```

```
public class Gui extends Application {

    private final static IntBinaryOperator PLUS = new BinaryPlusOperator();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Calculator calc = new Calculator();

        // display parts of formula in ListView
        ListView<String> formulaPartsDisplay = new ListView<>(calc.getFormulaParts());
        formulaPartsDisplay.setMaxHeight(30);
        formulaPartsDisplay.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);

        Text operand = new Text();
        operand.setFont(Font.font(20));

        // display current input in Text
        operand.textProperty().bind(calc.operandProperty());

        VBox display = new VBox(5, formulaPartsDisplay, operand);
        display.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
        VBox.setVgrow(display, Priority.NEVER);
        display.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.GREEN, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, CornerRadii.EMPTY, new BorderWidths(3))));

        Button plus = new Button("+");
        Button eval = new Button("=");
        Button d1 = new Button("1");

        // event handlers invoke appropriate methods of Calculator
        plus.setOnAction(evt -> calc.addBinaryOperator(PLUS));
        eval.setOnAction(evt -> calc.evaluate());
        d1.setOnAction(evt -> calc.addDigit((byte) 1));

        GridPane buttons = new GridPane();
        buttons.add(d1, 0, 0);
        buttons.addRow(1, plus, eval);

        Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(display, buttons));

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```